# 4K Stereoscopic 3D TV Set

Tags: hdmi, 4k, 3d-display

In my recreational time, I consider myself a "prosumer". I like making and watching videos and movies, and I'm considering upgrading my FullHD home theater system.

I've seen options such as the Optoma branded projectors, and they come with 3D viewing glasses in the purchase option in my local online shops.

But I'm a bit worried that the images may be dimmed during daytime when the sunlight is bright, so I want a TV as a backup option.

What are the recommendations for 3D 4K TV sets? Requirements:

- Physically and visually 4K,
- Native HDMI 3D signal support,
- No startup adverts.
- (Optional) ARC (Audio Return Channel).

Comment: You should verify that there is even any 4K media to play in 3D. IIRC the blu-ray releases for 3D movies are 1080p, so the 4K is unused there. And the 4K blu-rays aren't 3D (That's 8x the data of the regular 1080p version!). There isn't much demand for a device that can play both so TV manufacturers usually make one or the other in any given model.

Comment: @Romen Electronics salesmen said the same to me as well, but I'm a "prosumer", so I have the desire to author content in such format. Even if there aren't 4K 3D Movies, there are other media that output in such format, e.g. games.

Comment: Nvidia has officially ended support for 3D Vision, so in that case even games have abandonned 3D. Although the cards still technically support the 3D HDMI signal mode, they won't "upgrade" normal games to 3D anymore.

Comment: I have to agree. 3D passed its peak quite some time ago. Most manufacturers have even stopped making 3D screens, no-one's making 3D movies any more, IMAX is the biggest 'new thing' [even though it's eminently a poor choice for a 16:9 home screen. I'm dubious of the label 'prosumer' because it doesn't tell me what you think that entails. I speak as someone who work in the TV/film industry, though not behind the camera. I do that only as a hobby… & as a hobby, editing 8x4k multicam streams is a bit much for my mere 12-core Xeon; I'd hate to be trying to do that to 3D 4k ;))